# Postgresql trigram text search with pg_search results order

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, full-text-search, pg-search

I implemented a trigram search using pg_search gem on rails. https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search

The problem is that sometimes the order of returned results doesn't seems right according to the definition of the trigram search that shows the gem documentation:

> Trigram search works by counting how many three-letter substrings (or “trigrams”) match between the query and the text.

My application receives string input from the user ("111 Streetname") and returns a list of addresses that matches the Address.full_string value with approximate search with trigram.

## List of search examples

**Trigram search:  "1493 cambrid"**

- Results:

  - 100 Cambridgeside Pl
  - 100 Cambridgeside Pl
  - 150 Cambridgepark Dr
  - 1575 Cambridge St
  - 1573 Cambridge St
  - 1493 Cambridge St

**Trigram search:  "1493 cambr"**

- Result:

  - 1493 Cambridge St

**Trigram search:  "1493 cambri"**

- Results:

  - 1575 Cambridge St
  - 1573 Cambridge St
  - 1493 Cambridge St

**Trigram search: "1493 cambridge"**

- Results:

  - 1493 Cambridge St
  - 5 Cambridgepark Dr
  - 7 Cambridgepark Dr
  - 100 Cambridgeside Pl
  - and many more

## Question

¿Why isn't "1493 Cambridge St" always on top of the results? ¿Do I need to change the query of the trigram search or is it just the way the algorithm works?

## Query example

```
SELECT "addresses".*, (ts_rank((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("addresses"."full_string"::text, ''))), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || '1493' || ' ''') && to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'cambridge' || ' ''')), 0)) AS pg_search_rank FROM "addresses" WHERE (((coalesce("addresses"."full_string"::text, '')) % '1493 cambridge')) ORDER BY pg_search_rank DESC, "addresses"."id" ASC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you quote the manual on [*trigram search*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html), you are actually operating with the `ts_rank()` function from [*text search*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-textsearch.html).

If you order the results by

```
(addresses.full_string <-> '1493 cambridge')
```

... you get what you ask for.
[`<->` being the trigram "distance" operator.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-OP-TABLE)

You may also want to use the `%` ("similarity") operator in the `WHERE` clause. Ideally you would have a GiST index with `gist_trgm_ops` on the column for this.